# How can I grab a value between two tags from a string

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I am trying to grab data from a webpage. I have downloaded the webpage into a string variable.

I am wondering how I can grab the value between two tags. I have included a snippet of the downloaded string and the value I want is `895`

```html
<div class="split2r right">


                    <strong>Avg. asking rent in M4:</strong> 
                    <strong class="price big">&pound;897 pcm</strong><br>
                    <strong>No. of properties to rent in M4:</strong> <strong><a data-ga-category="Area stats" data-ga-action="properties_to_rent" data-ga-label="/tracking/home-values/results/" href="/to-rent/property/manchester/isaac-way/m4-7ed/">225</a></strong>

            </div>
```

A code example would be great.

Comment: Will this string always be the same?  Will it always start with &pound; and be 3 characters?

Comment: seach: "HTML agility pack"; meh, I'll save you some time: [NuGet (for install)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack), [Samples, etc](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: yes the tags surrounding the value will never change only the value but the value can be any amount of characters.. i can be 1 - 99999

Comment: "HTML agility pack" looks good but no documentation and only one example that is not useful

Comment: It is pretty straight forward to use despite the fact it lacks documentation. If you run into a problem you can always ask in [discussions](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions) and of course we're here..

Comment: could you not post an example that i can adapt... it would help me an awful lot. I know people on here do not like doing other people work but ill figure it out if i see an example

Comment: Try loading it as a `XmlDocument` using `xml.LoadXml(string_variable)` and you can access the tags as nodes.

Comment: its not written in xml tho.... will that be a problem as its in asp.net

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite easy using the [HtmlAgilityPack library](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML.

The first step is to add a reference to the `HtmlAgilityPack` library. Then you can start parsing the HTML:

```
const string Html = "<strong>Avg. price:</strong> <strong class=\"price big\">&pound;895 pcm</strong><br><strong>this is the price of zed headphones</strong>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Html);
```

The next step is to find the element you are looking for, in this case that is the `<strong>` element with its `class` set to `price big`:

```
var priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//strong[@class='price big']");
```

Now our final step is to retrieve the actual number from the node's `InnerText` property. Probably the best way to do this is through a regular expression, which can be quite simple if we assume that the required number is the only number in the inner text of the node:

```
var priceMatch = Regex.Match(priceNode.InnerText, @"(\d+)");

Console.WriteLine(priceMatch); // Will output 895
```

Comment: thanks but it never worked: error "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Lets Rent.dll but was not handled in user code" 

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."             it must not find the node

Comment: @ChrisDevine Then your HTML must actually be different from what you posted. My example uses precisely the HTML you posted. Could you double check if the HTML is indeed the same?

Comment: well there is a whole page of HTML that was just a little snippet... should it still work. i will edit to real html now

Comment: also i tried the exact code you copied and it just give me a more than sign as the output

Comment: am sorry your sample code did work but it did not work when the html page was grabbed from the internet

Comment: @ChrisDevine Well, I don't know what's wrong then. I have created a .NET fiddle with your updated HTML but it still works: http://dotnetfiddle.net/qQrlNH That means that it not working on your machine is likely due to some HTML difference or copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = @"<strong class=""price big"">&pound;895 pcm</strong><br>";

    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, ">&pound;\d{0-5} pcm");

    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        Add To List  Convert.ToInt32(m);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will not work as the value is always diffrent... it will not always be 895

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Comment: @ChrisDevine Thats kind of the point of my answer...

and Fedor, I know its ugly but if its a personal program that is upkept and you keep in mind this could easily break, theres nothing wrong with doing it.

Comment: I see now :D but i got this error "Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence C:\Development\Lets Rent\Lets Rent\Account\Default-TestingPage.aspx.cs 79 57 Lets Rent
"    and the d in the expression was underlined

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string value is called "source" and all extracts are formatted as the example

```
var value = Regex.Replace(source, @"\D", string.Empty);
```